# regex for url in image tag with unknown part in the middle using PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, silverstripe

Here are the ingredients:

- html text
- oldpath, e.g. /assets/uploads/
- newpath, e.g. /assets/newFolder/
- oldfilename, e.g. oldImage.jpg
- newfilename, e.g. newImage.jpg

in the html there are images like this:

```
<img src="[oldpath]xxx[oldfilename]" />
```

What I want to do is write a regex that can replace instances of this with a new file name and path using PHP and/or MYSQL (prefer PHP) so that it becomes:

```
 <img src="[newpath]xxx[newfilename]" />
```

xxx are a bunch of characters, e.g. /_resampled/croppedimage170170-, but I dont know the exact content of xxx.

So i want to end up with something like

```
<?php
$newHtml = preg_replace(MAGIC GOES HERE);
```

Thank you in advance.

Nicolaas

Comment: `your_src.replace(oldfilename, newfilename)`. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: See [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: I dont think that this is really going to do the trick. Looks more like JS.

Comment: And how exactly u want to determine the new filename ?

Comment: @DarkBee, I have the new filename.  I could do a straight str_replace(old, new, html), but the xxx part in the middle makes it a little harder. I dont know the xxx part in the middle and I dont want to replace the path and the filename independently as this might replace too many instances.

Comment: Here let me just write that regex for you.

Comment: So all your filenames are the same then ?

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be `/oldPath(.*?)old filename/` and the replacement would be `newPath$1newFilename`. I.e.

```
preg_replace('/oldpath(.*?)oldfilename/', 'newpath$1newfilename', originalHTMLstring);
```